# docker build: returned a non-zero code: 127**

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker file is

```
FROM alpine:3.4
#RUN apk update && RUN apk add curl && RUN apk add vim && RUN apk add git 
RUN apk update
RUN apk add curl
RUN apk add vim
RUN apk add git
```

I am able to execute it

when I change this dockerfile to

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update && RUN apk add curl && RUN apk add vim && RUN apk add git
```

Getting error:

```
/bin/sh: RUN: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update && RUN apk add curl && RUN apk add vim && 
RUN apk add git' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

What am I missing. I am new to docker.

Comment: 'RUN' is valid dockerfile, but all the text past 'RUN' gets passed to the shell.  So just removing the subsequent 'RUN's on the line will fix it.  "RUN foo && bar"

Comment: Thanks frnd..it worked

Comment: Still have the issue `returned a non-zero code: 127`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you don't need to repeat the RUN command after `&&` .  RUN is a Docker directive and is only needed once.

So if you use

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk update && apk add curl vim git
```

that should work better